# Continuity of functions in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the continuity of this function; it seems obvious, but somehow I don't know how to finish the proof.

Suppose $F:X\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ is continuous and, for $t\in[0,1]$, define $f_t:X\rightarrow Y$ by $f_t(x)=F(x,t)$. Prove that $f_t$ is continuous.

Let $U\subseteq Y$ be open. Then $F^{-1}(U)\subseteq X\times [0,1]$ is open and there are $V_1\in X$, $V_2\in[0,1]$ (open?) such that $F^{-1}(U)=V_1\times V_2$ (is this true?). Then for each $t$ maybe $f_t^{-1}(U)=V_1$.

This is for an assignment so I would appreciate some suggestions and not the whole answers!

Thanks

Comment: In a product of topological spaces, there are (generally) many more open sets than just those of the form $V_1 \times V_2$. Can you write $f_t$ as a composition of continuous maps?

Comment: I thought of writing $f_t=F\circ g_t$, where $g_t:X\rightarrow X\times [0,1]$ is given by $g_t(x)=(x,t)$. But is this immediatly continuous?

Comment: You probably know that a map to a product is continuous if and only if the component functions are continuous. That makes $g_t$ pretty immediately continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$i_t:X\rightarrow X\times [0,1]$ $i_t(x) = (x,t)$ is continuous,
$f_t = F\circ i_t$ is the composition of 2 continuous functions